# How to use the AngularFireList to display list in html

Tags: ionic3

I am able to save to firebase but could not retrieve the items as a list. It gives me the error as such: `Uncaught(in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument'[Object.Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`...

[image]

I am following a tutorial that still uses the FirebaseListObservable. But I can't get it to work since it is depecrated. Using the AgularFireList, I cant't list the items.

Below is how I try to retrieve the items from firebase to Ionic app:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2/database"; 


export class ShoppingListPage {
 shoppingListRef$: AngularFireList<any[]>

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, 
              private navParams: NavParams,
              private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.shoppingListRef$ = database.list('/shopping-list');
  }

  navigateToAddShoppingPage() {
    // navigate the user to the Add SHopping Page
    this.navCtrl.push('AddShoppingPage');
  }
}
```

This is in the html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingListRef$ | async">
      <h2>Item Name: {{item.itemName}}</h2>
      <h3>Amount: {{item.itemNumber}}</h3>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can update your code

```
export class ShoppingListPage {
 shoppingList: any[];

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, 
              private navParams: NavParams,
              private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
              database.list('/shopping-list').valueChanges()   // returns observable
              .subscribe(list=> {
              this.shoppingList = list;
              console.log(this.shoppingList);
           });
  }

  navigateToAddShoppingPage() {
    // navigate the user to the Add SHopping Page
    this.navCtrl.push('AddShoppingPage');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try update ur code.

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2/database"; 

@Component({
  selector: 'shopping-list',
  templateUrl: 'shopping-list.html'
})

export class ShoppingListPage {

 shoppingListRef$: AngularFireList<any[]>

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, 
              private navParams: NavParams,
              private database: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.shoppingListRef$ = database.list('/shopping-list');
  }

  navigateToAddShoppingPage() {
    // navigate the user to the Add SHopping Page
    this.navCtrl.push('AddShoppingPage');
  }
}
```

ANOTHER TIPS USING npm install firebase
A. Create service.ts
create constructor for detail data name from firebase. 
example: file service.ts in folder providers [img file service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzZbL.png)

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class Service {

productList: any;

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
   this.productList = firebase.database().ref('/shopping-list' );
}

getProductLists(): any{
    return this.productList;
}
```

B. GO to ur page.ts

```html
import { Service } from '../../providers/service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@ionicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-products',
  templateUrl: 'products.html'
})

export class ShoppingListPage {
productsList: any;

constructor(
    public nav: NavController, 
    public params: NavParams, 
    public service: Service, ) {
    
    this.service.getProductLists().on('value', snapshot =>{
    this.productsList = [];
      snapshot.forEach( snap =>{
        this.productsList.push({          
          id: snap.key,
          itemName: snap.val().itemName,
          itemNumber: snap.val().itemNumber
        });
      });
    });
    
}
```

C. in html

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list *ngIf="productsList.length">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of productsList">
      <h2>Item Name: {{item.itemName}}</h2>
      <h3>Amount: {{item.itemNumber}}</h3>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solutiion. But if I use this, then I wouldn’t be able to follow along the tutorial anymore because it will be a very different approach already. I am very new to Ionic so I have to follow this tutorial. But I’m pretty sure this solution will work. If you can, can you please update my codes so it won’t change too much.

Comment: Try change shoppingListRef$: AngularFireList<ShoppingItem> to shoppingListRef$: AngularFireList<any>

Comment: and this.shoppingListRef$ = this.database.list('shopping-list'); to this.shoppingListRef$ = database.list('shopping-list').valueChanges() and u forget // import pipe. there a detect import pipe component try disable it at top

Comment: I have done it as you suggested (please see edit in the question). I still get the same error (please see image). But if I use the 'import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';  and use the `shoppingListRef$: FirebaseListObservable<ShoppingItem[]>` I get the results I am looking for. This AngularFileList is new but I am having a hard time trying to implement it.